# Unable to install GTS package in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: python, ubuntu, makefile, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to import gts package in python

When I type import gts in python I get error

```
No module named gts.
```

I have tried installing it by [downloading folder](http://gerris.dalembert.upmc.fr/darcs/gts-stable/) and following [commands](http://gts.sourceforge.net/install.html):

```
sh autogen.sh
make
make install
```

But I am getting an error that:

> make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.

How do I install the GTS package

My system: Ubuntu 14.04

Comment: Can you post the outputs of the first three commands? Make sure you're following the instructions down to the t.  I know you say you have, but in my experience when something like this happens, usually you're missing some small detail in the instructions.

Comment: I'm confused as to what you're trying to do here. GTS is a C library. Even if you did install it, you wouldn't be able to import it in a Python interpreter, as it's not a Python module.

Answer (score 0):

You have attempted to install the GTS C library. What you want to install is
the Python wrapper for the GTS C Library. Do that by typing:

```
sudo apt-get install python-gts
```

in the console.